# Rank() SQL Or Something like that

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

hello there is any way to get an Account Balance for these like I would like to calculate Credit and Debit like

```
1 - 1000 
2 - 1000-500 = 500
3 - 500-700  = -200
```

and so on depend on date

There is any solution like rank or something to help?
thanks too much/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LAG` analytic function:

```
SELECT "Date",
       GREATEST(
         account_balance - LAG(account_balance, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY "Date"),
         0
       ) AS credit,
       GREATEST(
         LAG(account_balance, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY "Date") - account_balance,
         0
       ) AS debit,
       account_balance
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( "Date", account_balance ) AS
SELECT Date '2021-01-01', +1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT Date '2021-01-02', + 500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT Date '2021-01-03', - 200 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | Date | CREDIT | DEBIT | ACCOUNT_BALANCE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01-JAN-21 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | 0 | 500 | 500 |
> | 03-JAN-21 | 0 | 700 | -200 |

---

To calculate in the opposite direction:

```sql
SELECT "Date",
       credit,
       debit,
       SUM(credit-debit) OVER (ORDER BY "Date") AS account_balance
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( "Date", credit, debit ) AS
SELECT Date '2021-01-01', 1000,   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT Date '2021-01-02',    0, 500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT Date '2021-01-03',    0, 700 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | Date | CREDIT | DEBIT | ACCOUNT_BALANCE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01-JAN-21 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | 0 | 500 | 500 |
> | 03-JAN-21 | 0 | 700 | -200 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aaf57ab22a06d377d15171be573df433)*

Comment: I would like to calculate it from the account balance if there is a value in line number one will be = 1000 then I would like to get the line number two 1000 from the account balance - debit = 500 and so on

Comment: @AbdelrhmanAhmed Updated to calculate the credit/debit from the account balance.

Comment: i really appreciate your support but i can`t understand so let me type the code here

Comment: select INVOICE_DATE, CREDIT_AMOUNT, DEBIT_ AMOUNT FROM INVOICE  and then I would like to create a new column like account_balance  calculate the two values ( CREDIT_AMOUNT AND DEBIT_AMOUNT ) and all calculation will be based on the current account balance you understand me ? :)

Comment: I'm really sorry for bother you

Comment: @AbdelrhmanAhmed [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c459e81408519aa8360d71c870b03cb) like that?

Comment: Thank you too much, really thank you <3